# Append file extension on names of multiple files

Tags: linux, shell, filenames

I have a folder containing 500 files like this:

```
 xaa
 xab
 xac
 xad
 aae
 aaf
```

I want to add ".txt" to the end of all of them to get something like this:

```
xaa.txt
xab.txt
xac.txt
xad.txt
```

How would this be done?

Comment: There may be a duplicate Q out there, but the currently-linked one doesn't have answers for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With simple ***find*** + ***mv*** command:

```
find yourfolder/ -type f -exec mv {} {}".txt" \;
```

Comment: yes, works ....

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. Here are three:

```
rename 's/$/.txt/' ???    # Might be prename on some systems

for f in ???; do mv "$f" "$f.txt"; done

find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} '{}.txt' \;
```